# VB 6 application throwing error The server principal (username) unable to access the database production under the current security context

Tags: sql, vb6

I am working with a legacy application that was written in vb 6. In the code there is an embedded sql query. I am trying to make a left join on another database. using the following select statement:

```
SQL = "select h.case_ref, t.t5_desc, h.narisno, h.valuation_ref, h.claimant, h.t5," & _
" h.claim_amount, h.claim_date , h.dateofentry, h.case_completed, l.project_short_name AS narisno_desc, h.case_type "
If blnFromCaseRefSelection = True Then
    SQL = SQL & " from case_header h left join lut_t5 t on h.t5 = t.t5 left join" & _
    " [production].[dbo].[xxx_01_project_attributes] l on  h.nno = l.pin where h.case_ref = '" & cboCaseRef.Text & "'"
Else
    SQL = SQL & " from lut_fileref f, case_header h left join lut_t5 t on h.t5 = t.t5" & _
    " left join lut_nno n on h.nno = n.nno Where h.case_ref = f.case_ref" & _
    " and f.ha_fileref = '" & xxoHAFileRef.Text & "'"
End If
```

> error : The server principal (username) unable to access the database
>   production under the current security context

Any idea of how ui can solve this, my experience with VB 6 is basic

Comment: This is a bit hard to read, can you edit the question use the {} in the toolbar after highlighting the code and add the correct returns and tabs.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with the SQL. Check your ODBC Connection and the userid you're using to access the Server - I assume it's SQL Server - but you don't say. You need to check permissions on the userid to make sure it is more than Public

Comment: @dbmitch thanks for the reply. when i run the same query in sql, it brings back the right result from the table i am trying to do left join on  ([production].[dbo].[xxx_01_project_attributes]) in the query above but when i embed this code in the VB 6 code, compile it and deploy the code into the environment that's when i get the error. The way it should work is that, i will provide a number into the search box and it will populate a vb form from the database. i read that my problem might be ADODB issue but im not really sure!

Comment: This reads as a permissions error between the two servers/databases.  The user context that is used when running from the app isn't sufficient/correct, while the user context when you run the queries "in sql" ( do you mean management studio?) is sufficient/correct.  This would not be a vb6 issue, as @dbmitch describes.

Comment: The fact that it runs correctly under SQL server directly doesn't necessarily mean that it will also run correctly under VB. As dbmitch has said, the problem is almost certainly with your connection. if you're using ODBC (and DAO), do as he suggests. if you're using OLE DB (and ADO), as you imply, check the `ConnectionString` property of your `Connection` object. It probably doesn't have proper login credentials.